# How to add more sampling points to data in python

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry, sampling, curve

[enter image description here][1]i have code to plot the graph is.... this curve something looks like descreate fourier transform series how to do sampling with this and need to extract the sampling point values  for example i have 10 points to plot the graph what are the values in between the data 1 ,2 are points for the the graph and what are the values will get in between thease two points like 1,1.2,1.5,1.7,2 i want the values like this with my data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # For ploting
import numpy as np # to work with numerical data efficiently
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [15, 3.50]
fs = 100# sample rate 
f = 8# the frequency of the signal
# the points on the x axis for plotting
# compute the value (amplitude) of the sin wave at the for each sample
x=df["efficiency"]
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*f * (x/fs)) 
#this instruction can only be used with IPython Notbook. 
# showing the exact location of the smaples
plt.xlim(0, 75)
xdata = line.get_xdata()
ydata = line.get_ydata()
plt.stem(x)
plt.plot(x)
```

with bilow data i plotted graph which something looks like this [enter image description here][1]

efficiency

```
0
0
59.02
60
56.54
56.54
62.63
61.94
61.94
62.9
59.02
0
0
0
59.02
60
56.54
56.54
62.63
61.94
61.94
62.9
59.02
0
0
0
59.02
60
56.54
56.54
62.63
61.94
61.94
62.9
59.02
0
0
0
59.02
60
56.54
56.54
62.63
61.94
61.94
62.9
59.02
0
0
0
59.02
60
56.54
56.54
62.63
61.94
61.94
62.9
59.02
0
0
0
59.02
60
56.54
56.54
62.63
61.94
61.94
62.9
59.02
0


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIORB.png with above code i am trying to plot more sampling points i didn't get it how to do that any idea please help to get it response would really appreciated


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmPb6.png
```

Comment: you can add more points by doing extrapolation.

Comment: how to do that can you explain me

Comment: from where you optain the points? is it a function?

Comment: well your code is not very clear, since you are plotting `x`, but `x` doesn't exist in your code. You have a variable `fs` that controls the sample rate. Have you tried changing it to a higher value?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I would rather do interpolation than extrapolation. In any case we need the fucntion from where you obtained the points

Comment: Yup, wrong wording.

Comment: sorry for that i added the x data points now in my code i mentioned above the jupyter notebook cell i tried with higher interval also

Comment: edited code now and added x data points values

Comment: for normal sinusoidal wave i can get more data points and sampling but unable to get data points for this descreate fourier wave

Comment: can any one help me